# C++ template not compiling on Linux GCC

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a piece of code which compiles fine on Microsoft Visual Studio, but not on Linux Eclipse GCC.

This is the code:

```
template <class KEY, class BASEMAP>
class CGenericKeyToPointerMap : public std::map<KEY, BASEMAP>
{
private:
    iterator        tmpSearchIterator;

};
```

The compilation output is:

```
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/test.d" -MT"src/test.o" -o "src/test.o" "../src/test.cpp"
../src/test.cpp:22:2: error: invalid use of template-name ‘std::iterator’ without an argument list
  iterator  tmpSearchIterator;
  ^~~~~~~~
../src/test.cpp:22:2: note: class template argument deduction is only available with -std=c++17 or -std=gnu++17
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/iostream:39,
                 from ../src/test.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:118:12: note: ‘template<class _Category, class _Tp, class _Distance, class _Pointer, class _Reference> struct std::iterator’ declared here
     struct iterator
```

Comment: Do you have `using namespace std;` in your code?

Comment: Yes I do have it in my code.

Comment: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another reason to avoid the use of

```
using namespace std;
```

I'm guessing you want to use `std::map<KEY, BASEMAP>::iterator` instead of `std::iterator` in the line

```
iterator        tmpSearchIterator;
```

In that case, use

```
using iterator = typename std::map<KEY, BASEMAP>::iterator;
iterator        tmpSearchIterator;
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't quite understand where I should add this additional line.
I have tried adding it inside the class just above the "iterator" line as well as outside but that caused other errors.

Comment: @yaronkl, try the updated line. If that does not work, please post a [mcve].